# Adding elements from the inputted list

Tags: python, list

Hey guys just a newb question about adding elements from the loop. I wanted to get the sum of the list of elements depending on the number the user inputted but I really dont know what kinda syntax or anything to make it display only the sum of the list, I know that I just have to declare a variable that equates it to the sum of the list, but my real question here is how to get the sum of the elements from the list.

```
b=int(input("Enter the value of N: "))
for num in range (1,b,2):
    print("Sum of odd numbers from 1 to",b,"is",num)
```

output:

```
Enter the value of N: 5
Sum of odd numbers from 1 to 5 is 1
Sum of odd numbers from 1 to 5 is 3
```

output I need:

```
Enter the value of N:5
Sum of odd numbers from 1 to 5 is 9
```

I needed the output to be 9 since 1+3+5, which are odd numbers are the ones I needed to be summed, which came from the list.

Comment: This just seems like a basic programming/python question. I recommend learning more about those, first.

Comment: You need `s = sum([i for i in range(1,b+1,2)])`

Comment: How is your current code remotely supposed to work? A minimum of a fair attempt at solving the problem is expected.

Comment: `sum(range(1,b+1,2))`

Comment: A couple of things. First, your range doesn't do what you think. List building with a range is right-open, so range(1,5,2) is just [1,3]. You need to do range(1,5+1,2) or range(1,5+2,2) to get [1,3,5].

Comment: Second, since your print statement is inside the for loop (i.e. it is indented with the for loop), it is going to print for each iteration. You need to sum over the range and then print afterwards. But honestly, some of the other comments are a better idea than using a for loop here at all.

Comment: thanks alot, and im sorry as well for having suck a basic question, I just needed to meet a deadline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the numbers and then print them.

```
    b=int(input("Enter the value of N: "))
    sum=0
    for num in range (1,b+1,2):
        sum+=num
    print("Sum of odd numbers from 1 to",b,"is",sum)
```

Comment: ah yeah, that way i could include the value the user gave into the process, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it quicker you can use the closed formula for the sum of the first *n* odd integers, i.e. [image]

Then your program would look like:

```
b=int(input("Enter the value of N: "))
if b % 2 == 1:
    s = ((b+1)//2)**2
else:
    s = (b//2)**2
print('The sum of the odd integers from 1 to', b, 'is', s)
```